# Combine two files with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble using pandas to combine two input files as shown in the data sample below. They start out as CSV files exported from WordPress. I load them into data frames. My idea was to create an empty output data frame and fill it by looping through each `id` in the first input file, but that seems cumbersome and not taking advantage of Pandas' strengths. And because I'm new to Pandas I can't figure out how to convert the list-type second file into my desired output format.

**input_file_1:**

```
id postDate
23 2016-10-03
24 2016-02-15
25 2016-07-22
```

**input_file_2:**

```
id key    value
23 name   smith
23 age    24
23 city   boston
24 name   jones
24 age    35
24 city   chicago
25 name   williams
25 age    21
25 city   dallas
```

**desired_output_file:**

```
id postDate   name     age city
23 2016-10-03 smith    24  boston
24 2016-02-15 jones    35  chicago
25 2016-07-22 williams 21  dallas
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Just curious why you capitalize Pandas/pandas. It's not capitalized, even at the beginning of a sentence or as a section header, in the McKinney book 'Python for Data Analysis.' See for example page 4. Does SO style call for the capitalization? If yes, shouldn't it have been capitalized throughout my post? In the first sentence it was left uncapitalized. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pivot` in conjunction with `join`:

```
In [126]: df1.set_index('id').join(df2.pivot(index='id', columns='key', values='value'))
Out[126]:
      postDate age     city      name
id
23  2016-10-03  24   boston     smith
24  2016-02-15  35  chicago     jones
25  2016-07-22  21   dallas  williams
```

explanation:

```
In [127]: df2.pivot(index='id', columns='key', values='value')
Out[127]:
key age     city      name
id
23   24   boston     smith
24   35  chicago     jones
25   21   dallas  williams
```